# Splitting array of string values into Rows Numbers Table Ref Error

Tags: redshift

I am trying to create a table that queries individual database records, but splits out values from an associated array into individual rows for the individual database record. So far I have created the numbers table that has numerical rows up to 255, but when I try to join that table to a table where I am splitting the array by string in the number table order, I receive an error `function split_part(character varying, "unknown", double precision) does not exist`. Any idea what is off with my setup?

Note: I am using Amazon Redshift

**Numbers Table:**

Sample query results

```
number
1
2
3
4
...
255
```

Query

```
SELECT 
    p0.n 
    + p1.n*2 
    + p2.n * POWER(2,2) 
    + p3.n * POWER(2,3)
    + p4.n * POWER(2,4)
    + p5.n * POWER(2,5)
    + p6.n * POWER(2,6)
    + p7.n * POWER(2,7) 
    as number
  FROM 
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p0,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p1,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p2,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p3,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p4,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p5,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p6,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p7
```

**Parser table query:**

Ideal query results

```
row_id, record_id, medium_name
1, 24, work
2, 24, test
3, 24, success
```

Query

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by 1) as row_id
        , test_lead.id as lead_id
        , split_part(test_lead.test_mediums, ', ', numbers.number) as medium_name
      FROM ${lead.SQL_TABLE_NAME} test_lead
      JOIN ${marketing_model_numbers.SQL_TABLE_NAME} numbers
      ON numbers.number <= regexp_count(test_lead.test_mediums, ',\\s') + 1
```

**Array value structure:**

```
["work", "test", "success"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numbers.number` is a `double precision`. But `split_part()` expects the third parameter to be an `integer` and the value isn't implicitly cast. Try to explicitly cast `numbers.number`.

```
...
, split_part(test_lead.test_mediums, ', ', numbers.number::integer) as medium_name
....
```